Apple auto renewal subscription - Availability changed to remove from sale - Auto renewal will be continue for existing subscribed users?
Problem statement:
We are going to introduce new subscription product(Auto renewable), and disabling the existing subscription product by changing availability to remove from sale, anyone knows what will be happen to existing subscribed user? subscription renewal will be continue for existing iAP subscribed users ?

I have already checked on Apple sandbox environment that renewals for disabled subscription are working fine for existing users, but not sure about production environment. If anyone have implemented this, please confirm about existing subscribed users
This is mentioning by Apple ->
Before discontinuing an auto-renewable subscription, remove it from sale to avoid additional sign-ups and renewals.
https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-subscriptions/set-availability-for-an-auto-renewable-subscription/

If a subscription is removed from sale, there will be no more renewals for that subscription
